# JWPlayer 7 Vulnerability

Tags: security, jwplayer7, data-uri-scheme

The jwplayer.js file for Version 7 is being rejected as a high risk vulnerability by the PaloAltoNetworks' firewall due to its use of the RFC 2397 "data:" URL scheme. This does not bode well for the new player.
Has anyone found a workaround or solution to this problem?